# form to insert data on meteor mongodb

Tags: meteor

i'm trying to save data on mongodb with a form on meteor and ti should work but it doesn't
i'm totally lost
i'm running meteor 0.7.0.1 on a windows 7 machine

bookshell.html

```html
<body>
  {{> addBook}}
  {{> bookshell}}
</body>

<template name="bookshell">
 <ul>
  {{#each books}}
   <li>{{subject}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
</template>
<template name="addBook">
 <form class="addBookForm">
  <input type="text" class="subject" placeholder="Subject">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add book</button>
 </form>
</template>
```

bookshell.js

```js
books = new Meteor.Collection("books");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.addBook.events({
  '.submit .addBookForm' : function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      books.insert({
        subject: $(".subject").val(),
      });
    }
});

Template.bookshell.books = function () {
    return books.find({}, {sort: {subject: 1}});
    };
}
```

someone knows why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change:

```js
'.submit .addBookForm'
```

to:

```js
'submit .addBookForm'
```

Also, you might want to scope your `".subject"` selector to the template instance:

```js
Template.addBook.events({
  'submit .addBookForm' : function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    books.insert({
      subject: template.find(".subject").value,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Templates have a `submit` event, and the handler will isolate the submit to the template. So unless you have more than one form on the template you can just do this:

```
Template.addBook.events({
  submit: function () {
    books.insert({subject: $(".subject").val()});
    return false;
  }
});
```

Note from the docs:

> Returning false from a handler is the same as calling both
>   stopImmediatePropagation and preventDefault on the event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are Template events on form submission. Just put the event on the button (and perhaps even remove the form, or prevent the default):

Give your button and id:

```html
<button id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary">add book</button>
```

And add a click event to it:

```js
Template.addBook.events({
  'click #submitbutton' : function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     books.insert({
     subject: $(".subject").val(),
  });
}
```

});